# Combining data fetch and array iteration

Tags: d3.js

Just trying to optimise some code and found that the routine in example 2 doesn't work and only returns the final item!   Any ideas why the obj isn't updated forEach?

Example 1

```
const spreadsheet = await d3.tsv(url).then(data => data.forEach(function (d) { 
let names =[];                       
    return names.push({"code": d.Code, "date": d.Date})
  
     }))                                                                                                  
   
return names;
```

Example 2

```
let obj = {};
const spreadsheet = await d3.tsv(url).then(data => data.forEach(function (d) { 
     
        if (!obj[d.code]) obj[d.code] = {code: d.code};          
             obj[d.code]['date'] = d.Date;        
           
      })
    
  return Object.values(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug is happening due to a misconception in the use of *await* and *.then()*.

There is no need to *await* a promise if you're handling it with *.then()*. The *await* keyword exists to avoid the use of *.then().*

Reestructuring your code to remove the *.then()*, we have:

```js
let obj = {};
const spreadsheet = await d3.tsv(url);
spreadsheet.forEach(function (d) {
    if (!obj[d.code]) obj[d.code] = { code: d.code };
    obj[d.code]["date"] = d.Date;
});

console.log(obj); // Object here
```

However, [if you're not inside an async function, you can not use *await*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). If that is the case, this means you'll have to stick with *.then()*, and the data can not be accessed outside the callback. You would have:

```js
d3.tsv(url).then((spreadsheet) => {
  let obj = {};
  spreadsheet.forEach(function (d) {
    if (!obj[d.code]) obj[d.code] = { code: d.code };
    obj[d.code]["date"] = d.Date;
  });
  console.log(obj); // Object here

  /* Everything that uses obj must be called inside the .then() callback*/
});
```

In both approaches above, the *obj* variable is a JSON where the key is the code, and the value is the whole object with the code, which I think is the optimization you're looking for. Using *Object.values(obj)* would return just an array, exactly like your example 1.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the explanation.  However, I'm still struggling with a working solution.   With your restructured code;    return Object.values(obj) produces an array with i item as before.  If return Object.values(obj) is executed inside .then the result is undefined.